# Deleting an row from a table results in insertion of another row in another table automatically? How to do that?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can anyone tell me how to make this happen?

It looks like a setting.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterDelete ON <yourFirsttable> AFTER DELETE
AS
    select @blah = <yourCol1>, @blih = <yourCold2> from deleted;    

    insert into <YourSecondTable>(..., blah, blih)
        values(..., @blah, @blih);
GO
```

Comment: Hi David. How can I find this delete trigger in my table? Basically it's already created by someone in my database and I just want to modify it.

Comment: EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'PRINT ''?'' 
    EXEC sp_helptrigger ''?'''